# Does Bamboo allows to SSH Jmeter master/slave public IPs or Bamboo always connects/SSH to Private IP only?

Tags: jmeter, bamboo, docker-machine

Automating the Jmeter distributed load testing using Bamboo agent (CI).
We have used Jmeter docker swarm for distributed load testing, used docker-machine to create Jmeter master and slave machines which will give public IPs of these instances (used dockerfiles for this). Able to run successfully from local machine (Linux/Windows), able to communicate master, slave and get results from local. However when wanted to use Bamboo agent to automate the process facing an issue. Bamboo is not able to SSH to these created master and slave machines (used .sh script task to run these docker files and create master/slave docker-machines). Does Bamboo allows to SSH Jmeter master/slave public IPs or Bamboo always connects/SSH to Private IP only?

Comment: Probably not a Bamboo issue, sounds like docker networking issue.  Can't tell without examples.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not sure if Bamboo issue or docker-machine. Used below command to create docker-machine which gives public IP by default. docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --amazonec2-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --amazonec2-region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --amazonec2-vpc-id $AWS_VPC_ID --amazonec2-subnet-id $AWS_SUBNET_ID --amazonec2-zone $AWS_ZONE --engine-label type=slave --swarm --swarm-discovery token://$TOKEN jmeter-master-node